# Display authorization header when logging in to api

Tags: header, authorization, openapi

I am using OpenApi do document an API, i have a path /Login which lets me specify Username and Password as parameters and returns a Bearer style JWT in the "authorization" header in the response.

For further use in the API this JWT is used with the "Authorize" mechanism so the other paths can be accessed.

Sadly the authorization header is only visible if i open the network tracing in my browser.

Therefore my question, can i somehow tweak my OpenAPI YAML so the value is displayed and can then be copy/pasted to the authorization for the rest of the API. I am using the latest swagger editor (https://editor.swagger.io/)

This is what i have specified

```
paths:
  /Login:
    post:
      servers: 
        - url: ....
          description: Local test server
      tags:
      - Login
      summary: Logs into the API and returns the authorization.
      description: Username and Password are passed in header
      security: []
      #- bearerAuth: []
      parameters:  
      - $ref: '#/components/parameters/Username'
      - $ref: '#/components/parameters/Password'
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Login'
          headers:
            authorization:
              $ref: '#/components/headers/authorization'
parameters:
    Username:
      name: Username
      in: header
      description: Username to authorize with
      schema:
        type: string
    Password:
      name: Password
      in: header
      description: Password to authorize with
      schema:
        type: string

  headers:
    authorization:
      schema:
        type: string
      description: Authorization token.
```

Comment: Is your spec `openapi: 3.0.0` or `swagger: "2.0"`?

Comment: *"Sadly the authorization header is only visible if i open the network tracing in my browser."* - can you clarify this? Access tokens are usually returned in the response **body**, not in response headers.

Comment: @helen Sorry, it is openapi: 3.0.0 and in the case of this API it is definitely returned as a header field.